# Output of the function call is unexpected

Tags: verilog

```
module func();
  function [31:0]factorial;
    input [7:0]a;
    if (a==1)
      factorial=1;
    else
      factorial= a*factorial(a-1);
  endfunction
 
  initial
    begin
      $dumpfile("file.vcd");
      $dumpvars(1);
      $display("Factorial of 1 = %0d", factorial(1));
      $display("Factorial of 2 = %0d", factorial(2));
      $display("Factorial of 3 = %0d", factorial(3));
      $display("Factorial of 4 = %0d", factorial(4));
      $display("Factorial of 5 = %0d", factorial(5));
    end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
Factorial of 1 = 1
Factorial of 2 = 2
Factorial of 3 = 6
Factorial of 4 = 24
Factorial of 5 = 120
```

If I change the output bit to `[7:0]`, then the output is different.

```
module func();
 
  function [7:0]factorial;
    input [7:0]a;
    if (a==1)
      factorial=1;
    else
      factorial= a*factorial(a-1);
  endfunction
 
  initial
    begin
      $dumpfile("file.vcd");
      $dumpvars(1);
      $display("Factorial of 1 = %0d", factorial(1));
      $display("Factorial of 2 = %0d", factorial(2));
      $display("Factorial of 3 = %0d", factorial(3));
      $display("Factorial of 4 = %0d", factorial(4));
      $display("Factorial of 5 = %0d", factorial(5));
    end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
Factorial of 1 = 1
Factorial of 2 = 1
Factorial of 3 = 1
Factorial of 4 = 1
Factorial of 5 = 1
```

Also, my understanding is that in non-automatic function, the same functions are being shared between all calls.  Then in first program, why are the values of different calls different?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you hit a case of an undefined behavior here. All functions defined in modules are by default `static`. That means that the function parameter `a` is static for all invocations of the function. So, every recursion modifies value of the same variable `a`. It will always be `1` after returning from all recursions.

Now, depending on the order of evaluation `a * factorial(a-1)` the argument will either be as passed to the function or `1`. It looks like *vcs* executes recursion first for `[7:0]`. As a result `a` is always `1` before multiplication. *Cadence* does it differently.

The way to fix it is to declare the function as `automatic`:

```
function automatic [7:0] factorial
```

In general you should avoid recursion in synthesizable code. You can use a loop in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about the fact that there is only one copy of function arguments and output for non-automatic functions. In the expression `a * factorial(a-1)` the language rules say the implementation is free to call the `factorial` function in any order before evaluating all operands. Note there is some implicit casting going on behind the scenes that can add extra steps the the evaluation and change the ordering. This can be represented using the following equivalent code explicitly in SystemVerilog.

```
factorial= 32'(a)*factorial(32'(a)-32'd1);
```

This could be the reason behind why you are getting different results depending on the declared resulting width of `factorial`.

Of course, recursive functions or re-entrant tasks should all be declared automatic so they each occurrence has a local copy of their variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to Generate the Factorial of any number

```
module test;

  function int factorial(int n);
    int result =1 ;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)begin 
      result *= i;
      $display("result %d %d",result, i); end
    return result;
  endfunction

  initial begin
    int n = 5; // Replace 5 with your desired number
    int result;

    // Calculate factorial
    result = factorial(n);

    $display("Factorial of %0d is %0d", n, result);
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: (Are you positive this isn't *System*Verilog?) I don't see this try to answer `Why are the values of different calls different?`

Comment: The provided code is indeed written in SystemVerilog.

The reason the values of different calls are different is due to the loop in the factorial function. It iterates from 1 to n, multiplying the current result by the loop variable i at each step. This cumulative multiplication results in the factorial. The $display statement inside the loop prints the intermediate results for each iteration, showing the progression of the factorial calculation. The output of the above code is ;-   result 1 1
result 2 2
result 6 3
result 24 4
result 120 5
Factorial of 5 is 120

Comment: The question is not why results of call with different parameter values are different. It asks about different results depending on bit width of the function.

Comment: The varying results could be due to integer overflow when calculating the factorial for larger values of `n`. If the bit width of the result (`int` in this case) is not large enough to accommodate the growing values during the factorial calculation, it may wrap around and produce unexpected results. Consider using a larger data type or handling overflow conditions to ensure accurate results for a broader range of input values.

Comment: Do you suggest overflow to be the cause for result 1 for parameter values from 1 to 5?